# Create 100 X 100 frame around camera screen

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, camera, avcapture

I am working on a camera based app. It is related to histogram. When I open up the app it should start the camera and it should make frame of 100 x 100 in the center of the screen. 
The camera starts showing the images on screen but I don't know how to make frame around the center of the screen.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a 100x100 frame on top of the camera image then just create a 100x100 frame in a png image with transparent background. Create a UIImageView with your 100x100 frame.png and add that view to your camera view